# Stackdriver REST api - getting multiple Time Series

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm trying to get multiple time series using stackdriver api. Specifically, GCP load balancer data.
Using the stackdriver dashboard I've created a chart with some params and it works well, displaying all different time series answering the filters.
I've copied the same params to the API playground and the json response returning a single time series (probably the first).

This is the query (taken from the playground console):

`return gapi.client.monitoring.projects.timeSeries.list({
      "name": "projects/my_project",
      "aggregation.alignmentPeriod": "60s",
      "aggregation.crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
      "aggregation.groupByFields": [
        "metric.label.cache_result",
        "metric.label.response_code"
      ],
      "aggregation.perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE",
      "filter": "metric.type=\"loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count\" AND resource.label.forwarding_rule_name=\"my_rule_name\"",
      "interval.endTime": "2018-11-16T15:04:05Z",
      "interval.startTime": "2006-11-15T11:04:05Z",
      "pageSize": 1,
      "view": "FULL"
    })`

REST response:

`{
  "timeSeries": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "labels": {
          "response_code": "0",
          "cache_result": "DISABLED"
        },
        "type": "loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "https_lb_rule",
        "labels": {
          "project_id": "my_project_id"
        }
      },
      "metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2018-11-15T13:12:05Z",
            "endTime": "2018-11-15T13:12:05Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.05
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "CPvK9vuH/qibZxJtIh0KEAoGCKXhtd8FEgYIpeG13wUSCRmamZmZmZmpPyoNaHR0cHNfbGJfcnVsZTI9chkKFWfdsfpYzovcmVzcG9uc2VfY29kZRAAciAKFG1ldHJpYzovY2FjaGVfcmVzdWx0GghESVNBQkxFRA=="
}`

The actual chart I'm expecting to get (from SD console - same params):
[image: expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request you pass `"pageSize": 1` which tells the api to only return 1 result. Removing this parameter would allow it to return up to 100k results in a single response.

As `"view": "FULL"` is passed, each result is a single point in the timeseries. If you remove the `pageSize` parameter or increase it and still don't get all of the points back in a single response because there are too many, you can pass the same request with `pageToken` set to the `nextPageToken` of the prior response to get the next set of results.

More information here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.page_size

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression the page size is per-series and not an incremental count of all of them. removing this value returned all metrics. Although I need only 1 point from each series so it's a bit overkill.

Comment: No problem! If you know the time of the point that you want, you can use the interval to limit just around that time and get back fewer points.